# Error: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. When trying to add roles/users to channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im getting the error `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.` when I try and set new channel permissions. My code looks like this:

```
interaction.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
    if (channel.id !== interaction.channelId) return;
    let newPerms = [];
    giveRoleAccess(staff, 'new', interaction).forEach((staffId) => {
        newPerms.push({
        id: staffId,
        allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages]
    })
    channel.permissionOverwrites.set(newPerms); [error is occurring from this line]
});
```

The return value `staffId` contains either role ids or user ids

My only thought to what could be causing this issue is that I'm trying to set new permissions with role ids and user ids and maybe discord.js only allows you to set new perms with one type of id.

Comment: I checked the official document of discord.js and couldn't find giveRoleAccess function if it is a custom function can you share the code? If it is not check what giveRoleAccess returns and control are they roles.

Comment: @TunahanAkdogan `giveRoleAccess` is  custom function I wrote that returns an array of strings where each string is the discord role ID, ex: `['1013966888419741778', '1013966946368229468']`

Comment: Can you try to set permission manually with one or two ids without using foreach or any custom function. Also staffId probably is a string after your function process it maybe it should be an integer or long try. Best way to understand what is wrong try manually giving permission.